# Why am I seeing separate “wslbridge” processes when running ConEmu with default settings?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

Running a WSL shell using default ConEmu settings leads to 4 identical `wslbridge-backend` processes. Is this WAD? What's going on?

Also, trying to track down where ConEmu is setting the SHELL=/bin/bash - it isn't in the environment portion of the settings. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
0  1000     3     2  20   0  36408  1064 ?      Sl   tty1       0:00 /mnt/c/Program Files/ConEmu/ConEmu/wsl/wslbridge-backend --check-version=0.2.5-dev -365479 -065480 -165481 -k8F18348889BDC33C7360F44A58FD451D7CAB50607C677566FF83C90F27E95DB7 -w8192 -t2048 --pty -c139 -r18 -l -eConEmuBuild=180626 -eConEmuPID=9540 -eTERM=xterm-256color -C~ -- HOSTTYPE=x86_64 _=/mnt/c/Program Files/ConEmu/ConEmu/wsl/wslbridge-backend LANG=C.UTF-8 USER=teddy PWD=/mnt/c/Users/Teddy HOME=/home/teddy NAME=lappy TERM=xterm-256color SHELL=/bin/bash SHLVL=2 LOGNAME=teddy PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games WSLENV=
conemu 180626 64 Preview
```

Here is a screenshot of Htop showing extra processes.

[image: Screenshot of Htop showing extra processes.]

Comment: wslbridge is the main hero which connects both WIndows and WSL world like SSH. Comemu just a console emulator. See the project here https://github.com/rprichard/wslbridge

Answer (score 0):

Like Biswapriyo mentioned, ConEmu is simply a skin through which you are accessing WSL components.

In my ConEmu Settings->Startup->Startup options, I have 
Specified named task: `{Bash::bash}}`, with selected task contents `set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -cur_console:pm:/mnt`

However, specifying "bash" is not necessary - it's the default for WSL. You can show this by Cmd-R, then run `wsl` from the windows prompt. It'll launch a bash window, and this is what ConEmu is doing.

I'm not sure about the "extra" processes, but WSL surely has a lot going on under the hood!